# Can I install Windows Drivers in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, compatibility

I do not know if the proper drivers are install because the system has a lot of lag and crashes at times. Can I install Windows drivers in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases drivers will be automatically detected and used by Ubuntu. In the case of proprietary drivers you need to add them by going to System Settings > Additional Drivers.

In some cases, such as wireless cards, you can use Windows drivers by using 'wrappers'.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know U can not do this ,Ubuntu comes already with the necessary drivers for the System ,however for the video cards sometimes are problems with resolution compatibility , so there are additional drivers for specific video cards as Nvidia and Ati (for Ubuntu) and some drivers as my sis vga 771/671 video card  U can make a configuration using xorg config so that U may have a decent 2D and a good resolution,but the answer is NO, drivers for Windows U can not install in Ubuntu.