# Can I get my huion RTE-100 drawing tablet to work on ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, tablet, wacom

[this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204404/can-i-install-windows-drivers-in-ubuntu) talks about how they managed to use wacom drivers for another drawing tablet. I wish I could do the same with mine, because it won't even work at all on ubuntu. It doesn't even work with open source drivers (my friend's XXXX works with those drivers). I was wondering if my model would be capable of using the same drivers as another tablet and get it working that way.

Comment: Huion has released Linux drivers for some models. Unfortunately yours is NOT one of them.

Comment: Well that was my fear, unfortunately that means I will just have to rely on my main PC meanwhile. However, Huion has been on a streak of releasing drivers for linux and they claim that this model should be getting a linux driver soon :D